# Surefire JUnit test does not log failed Assume in test xml files

Tags: java, maven, junit, surefire

I am using

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
</plugin>
```

and

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

to test my project.

I have a very simple test method

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    Assume.assumeTrue("I am broken, so I am ignored", false);
    // some tests
}
```

When I build the project with maven, I get the following code snippet in the surefire xml file

```
<testcase name="test" classname="com.stackoverflower.experiment.Test" time="0">
    <skipped/>
</testcase>
```

I do not think this is the correct behavior of surefire, since assumption failures are treated the same as ignored, it should follow the same logging standard as ignored.  [This JIRA](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-537) clearly says the reason should be logged.

What do you think?  Is there a workaround to get that message into the xml file?

Thanks

**Update 1**

The reason I cannot use @Ignore is because I do not want to hard code a test as ignored.  I want it to be skipped based on some precondition that cannot be determined at coding time.

Comment: Don't you have `@org.junit.Ignore` at the top of your test class?

Answer (score 0):

The `Assume` methods mostly used in [JUnit Theories](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/experimental/theories/Theories.html) when combinations of `DataPoint`s are not valid for a given `Theory`. You should be using the [`Assert`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) class, not `Assume`. Here is your example test, re-written to use the correct class:

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException {
    Assert.assertTrue("I am broken", false);
    // some tests
}
```

It is meant for false assumptions to be ignored, as mentioned in the [Javadoc for Assume](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html)